# Two JPanels in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

(Edited)
Okay I most likely asked the wrong question.

I had checked up on layout managers prior to posting and the border layout seemed closest to what I had hoped to achieve. However, it is limited to five areas.

Below is a picture of the interface i am trying to split into various classes
[interface image http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/2355/mockuphp.png](http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/2355/mockuphp.png)

it consists of various JPanels and I honestly wasn't sure about it from all the previous questions asked and from reading up the layout tutorials because it seems too complicated.

So i guess the righ question i should have asked is - Is it possible to have all those JPanels fit into the JFrame to look exactly like that by using a layout manager? if not is there another way of achieving this?

My aim is to prevent having a long class of code.

(Original question)
I am quite aware there are many duplicate questions on here, i have read a lot of them and still cant figure out where i stand.

I am a newbie to java and really need help figuring this out.

Here are the two panels i am trying to add to a JFrame. (Made them this simple so i can test to carry on once it is working).

First JPanel

```
package main;
/**
*
* @author Dell
*/
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJPanel
 */
public NewJPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
}
```

The second panel is exactly the same except that it is called NewJPanel1

How can I put these two into one JFrame side by side please?

Comment: Surely your reading has lead you to recommendations to study and use layout managers, right? I'd start with the GridLayout -- Google the tutorial as it will explain all. Edit: some links you will need: [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), [Laying Out Components within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

Comment: Layout Managers tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Answer (score 1):

Swing uses layout managers to lay out components contained in a container. You could use a BorderLayout and place your two panels at LINE_START and LINE_END, or at LINE_START and CENTER, or at CENTER and LINE_END, depending on what you want.

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), it has lots of helpful information, and has a [full chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) dedicated to layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with NetBeans so I'd suggest you just use the [GUI Editor](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html). You can basically drag and drop your panels onto your JFrame and NetBeans will handle the layout (it uses GridBayLayout from memory).

Comment: Hi that's what i have done however, part of my group are requesting that the panels be created seperately in own classes and then combined at runtime

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can still do that. NetBeans allows you to subclass JPanel and use those elements in the GUI builder.